# Log4Net in asp: no file is created when logging a message

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I am using [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore](https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore). It should be straight-forward, but no log file is created and I ran out of ideas.

Minimal example (Startup.cs):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();
    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Global exception logger");
    logger.LogError("test");
    // Result: no file seems to be created under \bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0
}
```

Relevant infos from the .csproj file:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>

...

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.0" />

...

<Content Update="log4net.config">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

log4net.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender" >
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

In the log4net.config file, also tried adding `<file value="logfile.log" />` under `appender`.

Comment: I normally use the App.Config.  However, that requires a call to XmlConfigurator.Configure().  Possibly same issue here?

Comment: @GinjaNinja The XmlConfigurator seems to be [embedded in the code](https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore/blob/27efe08229a1733ed055bc8982d2a9b9274fbbfb/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore/Log4NetProvider.cs#L36) provided by the nuget package.

Comment: Assuming the configuration gets hooked up; use the `log4net.Appender.FileAppender` instead of the log4net.Appender.DebugAppender`; the `DebugAppender` doesn't write to file.

Comment: @pfx This was it. I am going to write a full answer about how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution given by @pfx in the comments:

> Assuming the configuration gets hooked up; use the log4net.Appender.FileAppender instead of the log4net.Appender.DebugAppender; the `DebugAppender` doesn't write to file.

This means that the `log4net.config` needs to change like so:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender" >
      <file value="C:\path\to\your\logfile.log" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

And also, `loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();` doesn't seem to automatically go find `log4net.config` (as it might be understood from the project's documentation). Instead, you must specify `loggerFactory.AddLog4Net("log4net.config");`.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about your problems, and also sorry to not be looking at SO to try to solve the problems that the library could have. Anyway, the most recent version of the nuget should go to find the log4net.config file into the executing assembly folder, without require to set the log4net.config file name directly on the extension.